# Beginner - setting up local host for Angular app using XAMPP on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, angularjs, xampp, localhost, windows-7-x64

I have taken a Angular App which works on Local host when I use visual studio IIE server.

I don't want to use Visual Studio and I am trying to test the app locally using XAMPP.

I am a complete beginner, and I cannot get the local host to pick-up the html initialization file. I have checked the following:

Skype is off and the port is set to 80 in XAMMP
the root server in HTTPd.conf is setup correctly (no slash at end)

I am getting a little confused as to 'how' angular will work on the XAMMP local host. 
Do I need to get Yeoman or grunt (seen these apps in some posts, but they seem to be for command line environment).

Any help, or even a pointer to a step by step set-up would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Got this sorted. I was over complicating things entirely, angular runs sweet on regular XAMPP, no Grunt/ Yeoman etc. required.

All you need to do is: 1. install XAMPP 2. Close Skype 3. Place you app, libraries and everything else in the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\

localhost/Angularappstartpage.html
BOOM!

it works.

You may need to adjust the port number on the localhost (default is 80 e.g. localhost:80/...)

You can also change the root folder in your XAMPP config setup to point to your local GIT.

Do this by changing the line in the HTTPD.conf file (click 'config' on the apache module)

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" to DocumentRoot "C:/myLocalGIT"

Hopefully this will help all the new guys out there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Angular is no different from a normal html web page, when it comes to working in a localhost.

Does your XAMPP work with standard HTML files?

Do you have any error generated?

Comment: Thanks a million for the speedy response! Just figured out that I need to put the files in the htdocs folder to pick them up on local host. I was just paranoid that a simple link to local host would be 'to straight forward'....! Onward and upwards ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Skype blocks the port 80, which is used for browsing. XAMPP uses the same port so exactly.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows-desktop

If you use mysql, also open first XAMPP and start your services and then keep working on your SO as always.